# .bat folder lock: how to change password inside Cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
    cls
@ECHO OFF
title Folder posnetki
if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" goto UNLOCK
if NOT EXIST posnetki goto MDLOCKER
:CONFIRM
echo Are you sure you want to lock the folder(Y/N)
set/p "cho=>"
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK
if %cho%==y goto LOCK
if %cho%==n goto END
if %cho%==N goto END
echo Invalid choice.
goto CONFIRM
:LOCK
ren posnetki "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
echo Folder locked
goto End
:UNLOCK
echo Enter password to unlock folder
set/p "pass=>"
if NOT %pass%== pass123 goto FAIL
attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" posnetki
echo Folder Unlocked successfully
goto End
:FAIL
echo Invalid password
goto end
:MDLOCKER
md posnetki
echo posnetki created successfully
goto End
:End
```

How to make password change from cmd not from code? Here I really need your help because I dont want everytime when I want to change password I need to open it by txt.

Comment: You could replace lines `6`-`14` inclusive with these two lines, `Choice /M "Are you sure you want to lock the folder"` and `If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo End`

Comment: You could replace lines `21`-`23` inclusive with these three lines, `Set "pass="`, `Set /P "pass=Enter the password to unlock the folder: "` and `If /I Not "%pass%"=="pass123" GoTo FAIL`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the password `pass123` inline inside of the script by using it while batch is running?

Comment: yeah bro i want to change it inside of script

Comment: why not just save it in different file, then set an option to either read it or change it.. much simpler than in the same file. If you respond, please use the @GerhardBarnard so I get notified of your response.

Comment: @Compo i did it but dosent work with me

Comment: @GerhardBarnard yeah i know but it will be more simple if i change it inside script

Comment: No it is not easier, you have to edit the file meaning you have to re-write the entire file or write to tempfile and rename.

Comment: _I provided improvements for your code as comments, they weren't provided as an answer to your issue_. I would also favor writing the password to a separate file, which can be edited and read by the running batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to focus on your code at all, I am simply going to demonstrate what you asked as the main question, that being *"how to change password via script"*.

Writing password to a file method:

```
@echo off
cls
:start
if not exist "%temp%\tmppwd.lck" (
  echo password file does not yet exist Please create a Password.
  goto chpwd
)
Choice /C TC /M "Select U to unlock T to test password"
  if %errorlevel%==2 goto chpwd
  if %errorlevel%==1 goto checkpass

:chpwd
set /p "passwd=Enter your new password and press Enter: "
set /p "passwdc=Confirm new password: "
if "%passwd%"=="%passwdc%" (
echo %passwd% > %temp%\tmppwd.lck
goto start
) else (
cls
echo Sorry, Passwords did not match, please retry
goto chpwd
)
:checkpass
for /f %%i in ('type "%temp%\tmppwd.lck"') do set "test=%%i"
set /p "attempt=Enter password to see if this works: "
if "%attempt%"=="%test%" (
  echo Passwords Match & pause
) else (
  echo Sorry, you entered the incorrect password
)
```

So as you can see, we create a new password, verify it and then write it to a password file. If the file does not exist, we simply do the exact same.

The `:checkpass` label demonstrates how you can use the password from the file. So where you currently use `if NOT %pass%== pass123 goto FAIL` we use the loop to read from file.